# Existe alguma maneira de modificar o que o modulo ira retornar em Lua?

Tags: lua, return

Eu quero saber se existe já que eu tenho um sistema de armazenamento de dados,no qual os dados ficam em uma tabela e quando o jogador entra,esses dados são armazenados em um script de modulo (O único que retorna alguma coisa). O problema é que não dá para ficar escrevendo por exemplo:

```
inventory=require(inventory)
inventory.Knifes=async.Knifes
inventory.ChosenKnife=async.ChosenKnife
inventory.Citrines=async.Citrines
--...
```

eu já tentei

```
require(inventory)=async
```

mas deu erro. Apareceu "Expected identifier,got ="

Por favor me ajudem,eu tenho pouco tempo!

Aqui está o bloco que eu estou trabalhando:

```
dss=game:GetService('DataStoreService'):GetDataStore('GameStuff')

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
    local key='id='..player.userId
    local async=dss:GetAsync(key)
    if not async then
        local save={Knifes={1},ChosenKnife=1,Citrines=,Coins=0}
        dss:SetAsync(key,save)
        async=dss:GetAsync(key)
    end
    local module=script.ModuleScript:Clone()
    module.Parent=player:WaitForChild'PlayerGui'
    --Modificar o valor retornado de module
end
```

Comment: Não basta fazer `inventory=async`?

Comment: Eu não sei,acho que não,pois antes de usar o require,inventory  é um módulo clonado na pasta PlayerGui,dentro do objeto do jogador .Nao dá para testar agora porque estou longe de casa. Se quiser testar por você mesmo,estou usando. ROBLOX Studio

Answer (score 1):

Acho que seria mais fácil adaptar uma classe para seu módulo inventory. Fora isso, parece que é apenas possível atualizar o valor de um módulo em versões do Lua maiores que 5.0, acessando a tabela `package.loaded`, na qual seu módulo requerido seria o campo `'inventory'`, por exemplo:

```
package.loaded.inventory = async
```

Talvez é desnecessário o módulo inventory, se `inventory == async` (`package.loaded.inventory` vai apontar à mesma tabela de `async`, assim como no seu último exemplo como corrigido acima).

Answer (score -4):

Em Lua, quando você cria um módulo (um arquivo com código Lua que pode ser usado em outros lugares), você normalmente define funções ou variáveis nele e, em seguida, o retorna usando a palavra-chave return. Por exemplo:

-- inventory.lua

local inventory = {}

function inventory.setup(async)
inventory.Knifes = async.Knifes
inventory.ChosenKnife = async.ChosenKnife
inventory.Citrines = async.Citrines
-- adicione outras configurações aqui conforme necessário
end

return inventory
Neste exemplo, temos um módulo chamado inventory.lua. Ele define uma tabela chamada inventory e uma função chamada setup. A função setup recebe um parâmetro chamado async, que presumivelmente contém os dados do jogador obtidos de algum lugar.

A função setup configura a tabela inventory com os valores adequados com base nos dados do jogador passados como parâmetro.

A última linha, return inventory, faz com que o módulo retorne a tabela inventory. Isso significa que quando você requer este módulo em outro lugar, você pode acessar a tabela inventory e todas as suas funções e variáveis.

Agora, vamos dar uma olhada em como você usa este módulo em outro script:

-- Seu script principal

local inventory = require(script.inventory)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
local key = 'id=' .. player.UserId
local async = dss:GetAsync(key)
if not async then
local save = {Knifes = {1}, ChosenKnife = 1, Citrines = 0, Coins = 0}
dss:SetAsync(key, save)
async = dss:GetAsync(key)
end
inventory.setup(async)  -- Configura o módulo com os valores necessários
local module = script.ModuleScript:Clone()
module.Parent = player:WaitForChild('PlayerGui')
-- Agora você pode usar o módulo com os valores configurados
end)
Neste script, primeiro requeremos o módulo inventory usando local inventory = require(script.inventory). Isso significa que estamos obtendo a tabela inventory que foi retornada pelo módulo.

Então, quando um jogador entra no jogo, obtemos os dados do jogador, configuramos o módulo inventory com esses dados usando inventory.setup(async), e então usamos o módulo conforme necessário.

Eu peguei do exemplo do ChatGPT, mas expliquei de outro jeito para ver se fica melhor pra você entender. Espero que você entenda tudo isso que eu falei :)

Comment: É difícil entender [**Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT e similares não é permitido no Stack Overflow em Português**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-e-similares-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-no-stack-overflow-em-por?cb=1)